# data is undefined after importing from a csv file with d3

Tags: javascript, csv, d3.js, data-visualization

I drew a world map with d3 and a json file, and are trying to draw circles on the map based on my data.

I imported my data with the `d3.csv()` function, as you can see below. However, `data` doesn't seem to be recognized for my function `function plot_points(data)`. When I type `data` in the console in the function, it keeps telling me `data is undefined`. It's interesting because I used the exact same code for another project before, and `data` would be recognized as an array of object. Can you tell what's wrong?

```
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      function draw(geo_data) {
        "use strict";
        var margin = 75,
            width = 1400 - margin,
            height = 600 - margin;

        d3.select("body")
                .append("h2")
                .text("Circle Graph");

        var svg = d3.select("body")
            .append("svg")
            .attr("width", width + margin)
            .attr("height", height + margin)
            .append('g')
            .attr('class', 'map');

        var projection = d3.geo.mercator()
                               .scale(150)
                               .translate([width / 2, height / 1.2]);

        var path = d3.geo.path().projection(projection);

        var map = svg.selectAll('path')
                     .data(geo_data.features)
                     .enter()
                     .append('path')
                     .attr('d', path)
                     .style('fill', 'lightBlue')
                     .style('stroke', 'black')
                     .style('stroke-width', 0.5);

        // debugger;
        // here data is undefined
        function plot_points(data) {
            // debugger;
            // here data is undefined as well
        };

        d3.csv("data/olympics_editions.csv", function(d) {
          // debugger;
          // here d is each data point/object, and seems to be working just fine
          d['Year'] = format.parse(d['Year']);
          d['Latitude'] = +d['Latitude'];
          d['Longitude'] = +d['Longitude'];
          return d;
        }, plot_points);

      };
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      d3.json("data/world_countries.json", draw);
    </script>
  </body>
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors?

Comment: @LarsKotthoff I was getting some sort of error about `.length` can't be used on `null`, but it went away somehow. Now I think I know why it's not reading data properly, because, just as Josh suggests below, the syntax for to d3 to read csv file is different from reading json or tsv files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the d3.csv documentation, the signature for the callback is as follows:

```
function(error, rows) {

});
```

try adding an `error` parameter to your plot_points function:

```
function plot_points(error,data) {

};
```

Comment: Josh is right, but I'm adding some details to this, which hopefully can help someone else in the future. For the function, it should be function plot_points(data){ }. And for importing the file, it should be d3.csv(data/olympics_editions.csv", function(d) { return { year: d.Year, latitude: d.Latitude, longitude: d.Longitude};}, plot_points);